# Sagemaker Distributed Data Parallelism not working as expected ( smdistributed.dataparallel.torch.distributed )

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, distributed-training

All,

I was trying the AWS sagemaker data parallelism approach for the distributed training ( using the two lib ) from smdistributed.dataparallel.torch.parallel.distributed import DistributedDataParallel as DDP
import smdistributed.dataparallel.torch.distributed as dist although the data is getting divided to all the GPUs("ml.p3.16xlarge" , 8 Gpus) however the training time is still not getting reduced either with single instance or the double instance.

**Earlier we tried with Sagemaker Inbuilt algo Resnet101 for the same data for 100 epoch training time was around 2080 sec  ( batch size - 64 ) which was the benchmark we wanted to improve with our distributed training**

Now when we tried distributed training with the distributed data parallelism approach with the same instance we are training for 20 epoch - time is 1600 sec ( batch size - 64) we are training for 20 epoch - time is 1300 sec ( batch size - 128)
we are training for 20 epoch - time is 1063 sec ( batch size - 258).

Even with different batch sizes training time is not improving much.

Train Data - 6016 Images.
Test Data - 745 Images.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are increasing the batch size and the number of instances together, so batch size per/gpu remains the same. The speed gain from doubling the instances seems not much. There could be several reasons:

1. your model has an I/O bottle net, if your data is on [AWS FSX](https://aws.amazon.com/fsx/) and fsx throughput is too low, it may slowdown training when trying to feed training data to all the instances. FSX throughput can be increased by increasing storage size.
2. You model has heavy CPU logic for data preprocessing, if may be competing for CPU resources with SM Dataparallel and starving the GPU. You can try batch process data preprocessing/augmentation, or use [Nvidia DALI](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dali/user-guide/docs/) to offload it to GPU.

If you are still facing issues please create a support case and require service team assistance. https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home?#/

Thanks!